Customizing Y-axis Major Ticks on Symlog Scale
I am working on a boxplot in Python using Seaborn and Matplotlib where the Y-axis is set to a symmetrical logarithmic scale. I'm attempting to place major ticks at specific intervals using a custom SymmetricalLogLocator, but I'm encountering unexpected results. Below is my minimal working example:
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
from matplotlib import ticker 

url = 'https://public.tableau.com/app/sample-data/titanic%20passenger%20list.csv'
titanic = pd.read_csv(url)

ax = sns.boxplot(x=titanic["age"].round(-1), y=titanic["fare"], native_scale=True)

ax.set_yscale('symlog', linthresh=1)
ax.set_ylim(bottom=-1, top=10**8)  # Extending the y-axis upper limit

# Attempting to set major ticks at specific intervals
subs = [10**i for i in range(0, 8, 2)]
ax.yaxis.set_major_locator(ticker.SymmetricalLogLocator(base=10.0, linthresh=1, subs=subs))

plt.show()

I intended to generate major ticks every two power steps with subs=[10**i for i in range(0, 8, 2)], expecting ticks at 1, 100, 10,000, etc. However, the actual plot displays ticks at every power of 10 (1, 10, 100, etc.). What am I misunderstanding or doing incorrectly in specifying the subs parameter for SymmetricalLogLocator?


The issue you are encountering with the subs parameter in the SymmetricalLogLocator stems from a misunderstanding of how this parameter functions within the symlog scale. The subs parameter is intended to specify the locations of the minor ticks between each major tick, relative to the scale of the major ticks.

base = 10 ticks = [base ** i for i in range(0, 8, 2)] ax.yaxis.set_major_locator(tkr.FixedLocator(ticks))
